# Incapsulation of the field representing an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

My class has a field that represents an array of objects that implement some interface each in a different way. More precisely each object in the array has a method to parse a file of some type and a method that returns corresponding supported file extension. Also my class has a Set which is filled by parsing the file.

```
private MyInterface[] myArray = new MyInterface[] {

    new MyInterface() {
        @Override
        public void parseFile(File file){/*parsing TXT*/}
        @Override
        public String getSupportedFileExtension(){return "txt";}
    },

    new MyInterface() {
        @Override
        public void parseFile(File file){/*parsing XML*/}
        @Override
        public String getSupportedFileExtension(){return "xml";},

    },            
};
```

My reasoning behind this approach is to keep all the supported file parsing capabilities in one piece of code. I want this array to be used both inside and outside the class.

If I return this array through a getter there is a risk to set it to null for example and break the program. 
So the questions are:

1. If I make the array final is it ok or there are better ways?
2. Is this a good programming approach or I should avoid such approach at all?
3. How do other people do such things?

Thanks!

Comment: I think making concrete subclasses is the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is using the [factory pattern](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). 
In your case you have a factory that receives a file extension and returns an object that implements a file parsing interface.
This way you can add more parsers later without changing the code and you have one single point where to ask for file parsing capabilities.

```
IFileparser parser = ParseFactory.getParser("text")
IContent content = parser.parseFile(file)
```

You can augment the factory to return the supported file extensions, sinch the factory knows all implementationn it holds.

Comment: Thanks! But I also want a user to be able to use "for each" loop, for example, to fill JFileChooser with filters.

Comment: In this case, the factory would throw an not supported exception.

Comment: Sorry, changed my comments too late